# how to load image with relative path in bitmap

Tags: asp.net, bitmap, relative-path

i want to upload image int the bitmap object from asp.net, the image is location under

```
/uploadedimages/sampleimage.jpg
```

whenever i use below code to load image in bitmap, i gets error saying Parameter not valid.

```
Bitmap b = new Bitmap("/uploadedimages/sampleimage.jpg") // this path is coming from database holded in variable
```

i tried to replace the slashes in path to "\" still that does not work.

can anyone tell me what could be the reason for the error and the possible resolution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if `uploadedimages` directory is in your `App_Data` folder then you should append the `App_Data` absolute path to your path:

```
Bitmap b = new Bitmap(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"), "/uploadedimages/sampleimage.jpg"));
```

Answer (score 7):

Use `Server.MapPath`. And it's a good practice to use the tilde char `~` to specify the web application root.

```
Bitmap b = new Bitmap(Server.MapPath("~/uploadedimages/sampleimage.jpg"));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `server.MapPath`, pass Url string as given below.

```
 Server.MapPath("../images/image.gif")
```