# Crop image to certain ratio from virtual path c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, crop, jcrop

I would like to Crop an image to a ratio of 5/3.5 when I have the following:

- Virtual path to image (~/Uploads/Images)
- X Point for Top left corner of image
- Y Point for Top left corner of image
- Image width
- Image Height

Here is an image showing what I mean:

[image: cropping]

The highlighted bits are what I have.

How can I achieve that with C# in my MVC Controller? I'd like to also store the image back to its original location, overwriting the old image if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use `System.Drawing` in asp.net even though its not recommended.

from what i understod you need a function with the following signiture

```
public static void CropAndOverwrite(string imgPath,int x1, int y1, int height, int width)
```

The task is fairly simple

```
public static void CropAndOverwrite(string imgPath, int x1, int y1, int height, int width)
    {

        //Create a rectanagle to represent the cropping area
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x1, y1, width, height);
        //see if path if relative, if so set it to the full path
        if (imgPath.StartsWith("~"))
        {
            //Server.MapPath will return the full path
            imgPath = Server.MapPath(imgPath);
        }
        //Load the original image
        Bitmap bMap = new Bitmap(imgPath);
        //The format of the target image which we will use as a parameter to the Save method
        var format = bMap.RawFormat;


        //Draw the cropped part to a new Bitmap
        var croppedImage = bMap.Clone(rect, bMap.PixelFormat);

        //Dispose the original image since we don't need it any more
        bMap.Dispose();

        //Remove the original image because the Save function will throw an exception and won't Overwrite by default
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(imgPath))
            System.IO.File.Delete(imgPath);

        //Save the result in the format of the original image
        croppedImage.Save(imgPath,format);
        //Dispose the result since we saved it
        croppedImage.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @decoherence. Why isn't `System.Drawing` recommended?

Comment: @Ciwan http://stackoverflow.com/questions/390532/system-drawing-in-windows-or-asp-net-services

Comment: Thanks, on this line `Image.FromFile(imgPath);` I get an error saying it failed to load the file! `imgPath` is `~/uploads/images`. Do I need to do anything special with the path?

Comment: @Ciwan use the full path, the path has to point to a single image   `c:/uploads/images/someImage.jpg` not sure if `~/uploads/images/someImage.jpg` would work but you can try

Comment: Thanks @decoherence. Aye just did some Googling and it turns out `.FromFile()` requires full path, else it'll look in same directory. Any idea how I can get from `~/uploads/images` to `x:/work/app/uploads/images/`?

Comment: @Ciwan the server machine is not yours? try ResolveUrl("~/uploads/images")

Comment: nope, the app will go on shared hosting. I won't own the server.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773660/how-to-load-image-with-relative-path-in-bitmap

Comment: This `var absoluteImgPath = Server.MapPath(imgPath);` fixed it.

Comment: @Ciwan sorry i never used asp.net ;)